# How to avoid permission deny with uid/gid 1000 after mount volume with docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am working on Docker version 1.12.5 with Fedora.

I try to create a Mongodb container with following command:

```
sudo docker run -v $PWD/db:/data/db -p 27017:27017 --name db -it username/mongo /bin/bash
```

Here is the response after I start mongodb:

```
# mongod
root@32c9349a75b8:/# mongod
2016-12-26T09:59:08.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=10 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=32c9349a75b8
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.1
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-12-26T09:59:08.644+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-12-26T09:59:08.646+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2016-12-26T09:59:08.646+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-12-26T09:59:08.646+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-12-26T09:59:08.646+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2016-12-26T09:59:08.646+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I checked the file permission of /data/db:

```
root@32c9349a75b8:/data# ls -al 
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   16 Dec 26 03:15 .
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root root  266 Dec 26 09:59 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  2 1000 1000 4096 Dec 25 16:24 db
```

If I just use mkdir to create the directory without mount it with a volume, the owner and group of '/db' will be root, I don't why the uid and gid are 1000 only after I try -v with docker run command. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission of the volume mount is the permission of the directory web you do a host volume (to a directory on the host). Fixing the permissions on this folder on the host itself resolves the issue.

Preferably, you can use a named volume instead of a host directory. Docker will maintain the volume and initial contents and the contained permissions will be copied from the image with this type of volume.

Comment: I have tried to change the permission of host dir. But it doesn't work, the volume mount has the same 777 permission as the host dir has. I also run container as root, which should have the permission to write in the dir in the container. But it doesn't work as I expected when I run commands like 'ls' or 'touch test'.

Comment: Did you `chown -R root.root db` on the host? What is your host? Linux, Mac, or Windows?

Comment: I am using Fedora 25. I tried chown, it does changed the owner and group into root, but it still output permission deny when I try to write into the dir.

Comment: I see the selinux bits showing in the directory listing. Try disabling that and rebooting to see if there's an improvement. If not, update the question with the latest output showing the new permissions.

Comment: I am facing same issue did you find any work around for that?